# what position do you think is good to place like button on cards

Tags: gui-design, android

[image]

i was designing a card and each card has like(heart) and comment.
i thought i would place like button on right side of card.
what are your suggestions.

other actions:
tap on card expands card info...so cannot have double tap like as in instagram.

Comment: What's the problem with the design you suggested? I se no problem putting the heart where it is now. Well, not in the middle of the picture of course, but on the card where it is now would be just fine.

Comment: Hey llias, Please check updated image of my design..previous one was instagram design

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Could you post an example of the whole screen, not just the card?

Comment: Heyyy llias ,please check updated image

Comment: it would be great help if you also suggest if there are any flaws on my home...any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

**Place the like button on the left side as other social networks do.**

This is because users are used to having the like button on the left side of the card/post. This complies with the [consistency usability heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/).

If you put the like button on the right side users will first look at the left side (because facebook, instagram, twitter have their like buttons on the left) and expect it will be there. However, it may take some time for them to detect that the button is on the right side. This is not intuitive.

My advice is to stick with the design that you have uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after looking at the updated images in the OP, here are my thoughts:

**How important is the interactions?** To me, the heard and the comment-buttons are essential, therefore I would make them a bit bigger so they will be easier to find and also easier to touch.

And what's the use of that third icon at the very right of the heart and comments?

**Suggestions**:

1. Make the interaction-icons larger.
2. Show that image to a friend a colleague, let them interact, look at how they're doing and ask them what they think of your design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should identify what is the main interaction you are looking for, to like or to add to favourite (Bookmark). Pinterest does it pretty well by have the PIN as the main interaction (with a huge red button) and the like and share interaction as secondary (in dark grey).

I would also increase the contrast in your design for legibility

Comment: So.... Like is main interaction.... So i think i would move it towards right... And comment at center... And on tap on card will expand more info about that wish and comments... And left Corner would be save (bookmark)

Comment: Worth testing it really quickly with first click test. Create the hypothesis and see how long it takes for people to complete the task. In this case, click on LIKE. There are tools out there such as Optimal Workshop to help you do it quickly and easy. Good Luck.